# Cloud dataflow workflow management through Luigi or Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, airflow, luigi, airflow-scheduler

I want my dependant cloud dataflow jobs to be managed through any workflow scheduler. Have anyone done it before? I have gone through the documentation parts of Airflow and Luigi as well but I really need some working samples.

Please help me with some relevant examples or links which can help me to explore and implement workflow management of Dataflow jobs.

Comment: Have you check this out, it has some example there as well: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py

Comment: What will your Dataflow jobs output in terms of results (e.g. GCS objects)?

Comment: luigi doesn't really include a scheduler component.